# _e() function get text_string from function

Tags: translation, localization

Can I print the text sring to be translated from a function for example

```
_e('echo text_function();', 'my_theme');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't this way. [See documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Placeholders) :

```
$echo = text_function();

printf( __( 'My string is %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $echo );
```